# Can I prevent authenticated users viewing my entire firebase database JSON file?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created a json file with over 5000 service technicians and I am working on a website where someone can search for a specific service based on location. I am new to firebase so assuming I store the below JSON in firebase database, it means any authenticated user can view all data by entering the firebase url.json? It would be unfair if the whole data is just outright available to view and just copy the entire data in a minute. Is there a work around?

```
    [
    {
        "name": "John",
        "Location": "Montreal",
        "title": "Electrician",
        "rating": "3",
        "phone": "5141234567"

    },
    {
        "name": "Paul",
        "Location": "Toronto",
        "title": "Plumber",
        "rating": "1",
        "phone": "5142234567"

    },
    {
        "name": “Rita”,
        "Location": "New Foundland”,
        "title": "Mechanic",
        "rating": "4",
        "phone": “5143234567”
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you want to allow authenticated users to search within your Realtime Database with the Clients SDKs (Web, Android, iOS) you indeed need to give them access to the entire tree of technicians (through adequate security rules).

One possible workaround is to use a [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) in order to query the database. You could develop a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) which receives the search parameters (e.g. geographic area) from the app front-end, then queries (i.e. searches) the database based on these parameters and finally sends back the results of the query.

Since a Cloud Functions runs with administrative privilege it will totally bypass the security rules. Therefore you can set up your security rules in such a way end-users cannot browse/fetch your entire database.

Note that using this method has some drawbacks, in particular in terms of pricing, realtime aspects, local caching, etc. The following [article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/should-i-query-my-firebase-database-directly-or-use-cloud-functions-fbb3cd14118c) describes in detail the differences between querying a Firebase database directly or by using Cloud Functions.

Comment: @tejiriafe Hi, did you have the opportunity to look at the proposed anwser?